# StoryBoard.Begin on ItemControl Items?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I have an ItemsControl, and its ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection. I also have a DataTemplate to display each MyPerson.

```
<ItemsControl Name="ic_People" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtPerson}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
<Canvas />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The DataTemplate itself is a bit complex, but part of it is an Image.

In codebehind I'd like to animate some/all of these DataTemplates, by moving the Image (using Canvas.Top etc).

My codebehind got stuck here;

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.From = 0;
da.By = 68;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.2));
sb.Children.Add(da);
object prop = Canvas.TopProperty;
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(prop));
sb.Begin(???, true); <---- needs a FrameworkElement
```

I have access to the ObservableCollection. How do I get access to DataTemplate or Person as a FrameworkElement (which is what the Begin method requires)?
thanks

Comment: is there a valid reason to do this in code not in xaml?

Comment: Perhaps it could. I'm just learning about WPF animations. MyPerson implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I need to position them at the start, and then through their lifetime move them around the canvas multiple times. I'd like the move to be animated (a smooth "walk", rather than a jump/teleport). Could a XAML defined animation detect that a property (ie UI_PositionTop) has changed, then smoothly move it to the new position, and then smoothly move it again when it changes again?